# Is C(K) a subalgebra in its bidual?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-algebras, vector-space-isomorphism

Let $C(K)$ be the Banach algebra of real-valued continuous functions on a compact Hausdorff space $K$. It is known that the bidual of $C(K)$ is again a $C(\Omega)$ space, for some compact Hausdorff space $\Omega$. Is $C(K)$ a subalgebra in its bidual? If the answer is in the positive, is $C(K)$ embedded in its bidual as a subalgebra via the canonical isometric embedding, that is, $f \mapsto \int_{K} f d\mu$, for each $\mu \in C(K)^{\ast}$?

Comment: $C(K)$ is complete, hence closed in the bidual.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy yes, I understand that C(K) is closed in its bidual. However, I wanted to understand how it is a subalgebra in its bidual? Is it via the canonical embedding?

Comment: $C(K)$ is norm-closed and weakly closed in its bidual just like any Banach space $X$ is norm-closed and weakly closed in $X^{**}$. Did you mean to ask whether $C(K)$ is weak*-closed in its bidual?

Comment: For any Banach algebra $A$, the caconical embedding $A\to A^{**}$ is an isometric Banach algebra isomorphism, where $A^{**}$ is equipped with one of the Arens products (e.g., see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4302117/definition-of-virtual-diagonals/4302412#4302412) Since $C(K)$ is Arens regular, Arens product on its bidual is unique, and coincides with the pointwise multiplication of functions on $C(\Omega)$.

Comment: @OnurOktay my question was concerned with whether $C(K)$ sits in its bidual as a subalgebra under the canonical embedding or not.  I haven't come across the notion of Arens product until I read your comment on it. Thank you very much. Could you kindly suggest few references on Arens product and $C(K)$ being an Arens regular?

Comment: It becomes a subalgebra if the canonical embedding is an *embedding*, that is an injective mapping. In other words, no element of $C(K)$ becomes zero in the double dual. Whenever we have an injective mapping, we can use it to identify the image with the domain. Or is the question whethe the canonical embedding preserves the products?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen yes, my question is whether the canonical embedding preserves the products or not.

Comment: @Joan I'm writing down the first reference that I recall, although perhaps it is not the easiest to read as an introductory textbook: You can find the Arens multiplications (vol.1 https://books.google.com.tr/books?id=3k0lKh6QY-QC) and the proof of "every C*-algebra is Arens regular" (vol.2 https://books.google.com.tr/books?id=zn-iZNNTb-AC) in Palmer's two volumes on Banach algebras.

Comment: I know that the question has to do with real-valued functions, but I cannot help to comment about the complex-valued case:

Given any $C^*$-algebra $A$, its bidual, $A^{**}$ is a von Neumann algebra and the natural embedding $j:A\hookrightarrow A^{**}$, $a\mapsto j_a$, where $j_a(\alpha)=\alpha(a)$ for all $\alpha\in A^{**}$, is an injective $*$-homomorphism (and injective $*$-homomorphisms are always isometric). Since $C(X)$ is a $C^*$-algebra, we have that $C(X)$ embedds isometrically, via the canonical embedding, as a $*$-subalgebra in its bidual.

Comment: @OnurOktay Thank you! I will check them out.

Comment: @JustDroppedIn Since the natural embedding, you say, is injective $\ast$-homomorphism, could you please tell me if $a.b \mapsto j_{a}.j_{b}$ is easy to observe or has a non-trivial proof? I am afraid I do not understand how this map preserves products.

Comment: @joan it is non trivial. The whole *-algebra structure of the double dual is a difficult thing unfortunately.

Comment: @JustDroppedIn I see. Thank you.